# MKV file Editor for Windows

Tags: windows, editor, mkv

I'm looking for mkv editor for windows.

Preferably,

- open, examine, edit and mux Matroska files (.mkv)
- merging and extracting streams, viewing information
- light-weight
- Open-source or Premium